# filling nan values with the another value which is already exist in this column

Tags: pandas, fill

I want to fill a column with value which is already exist in this column. I mean all value should be 'Texas' or another value (Which value is exist in the column).I tried ffill and bfill, it is working but there are a lot of dataframes which have nan values like this but their locations different for each dataframes. As you see, top and bottom values 'nan', so ffill and bfill is not working. How can I fill nan values with 'Texas'?

```
Date                       Country
2019-11-10 00:00:00            nan        
2019-11-10 01:00:00          Texas
2019-11-10 02:00:00          Texas
2019-11-10 03:00:00            nan
2019-11-10 04:00:00            nan          
2019-11-10 05:00:00          Texas
2019-11-10 06:00:00            nan 
2019-11-10 07:00:00          Texas
2019-11-10 08:00:00            nan           
2019-11-10 09:00:00          Texas
2019-11-10 10:00:00            nan         
2019-11-10 11:00:00            nan         
2019-11-10 12:00:00          Texas
2019-11-10 13:00:00          Texas
2019-11-10 14:00:00            nan        
2019-11-10 15:00:00            nan
2019-11-10 16:00:00            nan
2019-11-10 17:00:00          Texas
2019-11-10 18:00:00            nan          
2019-11-10 19:00:00            nan
2019-11-10 20:00:00            nan
2019-11-10 21:00:00          Texas
2019-11-10 22:00:00          Texas
2019-11-10 23:00:00            nan
                    .
                    .
                    .
2019-11-20 23:00:00            nan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need replace strings `nan` to missing values `NaN`s before your solution:

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].replace('nan', np.nan).ffill().bfill()
```

Comment: In this case, my solution is not working but your solution is very helpful thank you

Comment: @JuniorDeveloper - `my solution is not working` can you explain more?

Comment: If top and bottom values are nan, the column value start with nan or finish with nan.

Comment: @JuniorDeveloper - Answer was edited, can you edit.

Comment: I guess, this answer is better than the older one? It worked thank you again!